# Require does not find folder unless it's hardcoded

Tags: javascript, create-react-app

I'm using require to import constants as the path is dynamic by brand, so cannot use `import`.

If I hardcode the brand it's fine, but if dynamic, it say's cannot find the file:

This works:

```
const { COMPONENT_TEXT } = require('afs/componentText');`
```

This does not work (logging `brand` does show as `afs`):

```
const { COMPONENT_TEXT } = require(`${brand}/componentText`);
```

It show's error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'afs/componentText'
webpackEmptyContext
C:/path/to/src/common/components/NavItem sync /^.*/componentText$:2
```

Is there a way I can configure `create-react-app` to allow this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the soultion for that is something like this:

```
const { COMPONENT_TEXT } = {require(`${brand}/componentText`).default};
```